# How to print the composition of an array after each pass (bubble sort)

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to output the composition of an array after each pass however, I am unsure on how to go about that. I am unsure if the print function requires an extra loop that will print out each pass. The sample output should look like (I am also confused on how to make the output look this way since I tried putting cout << "Array"; in the print function but it was repeating after every print):

original array: 
6 1 4 2 8 (randomly generated)

passes of the bubble sort:

1. 1 4 2 6 8 (after 1st pass)
2. 1 2 4 6 8 (after 2nd pass)
3. 1 2 4 6 8 (after 3rd pass)

Final array:
1 2 4 6 8

The following is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

unsigned int seed = int (time(0));
const int SIZE = 8;
double random(unsigned int& seed);
void fill_array(int[]);
void buble_sort(int[]);
void swap(int&, int&);
void print(int[]);

int main()
{
  int num_set[SIZE];
  fill_array(num_set);
  print(num_set);
  bubble_sort(num_set);
  print(num_set);

return 0;
}

double random(unsigned int &seed)
{
  const int MODULUS = 15749;
  const int MULTIPLIER = 69069;
  const int INCREMENT = 1;
  seed  = ((MULTIPLIER *seed) + INCREMENT) % MODULUS;

return double (seed)/double(MODULUS);
}

void swap(int &num1,int &num2)
{
 int temp = num2;
 num2 = num1;
 num1 = temp;
}

void bubble_sort(int a[])
{
  bool sort_incomplete = true;

  while(sort_incomplete)
  {
     sort_incomplete = false;

     for(int i = 0; i < SIZE-1; i++)

        if(a[i] > a[i+1])
        {
            swap(a[i], a[i+1]);
            sort_incomplete = true;
        }
   }
 }

void fill_array(int a[])
{
   for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
     a[i] = 2 + (11 *(random(seed)));
}

void print(int a[])
{
   for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
      cout << setw(3) <<  a[i];
cout << endl;
}
```

Thank you. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The question is meandering all over the place, and does not match the shown code. For starters, this is bubble sort, not selection sort. Then, there is no such function called "print_array" anywhere in the shown code. And even if there were, fiddling something in there wouldn't accomplish anything useful, since there wouldn't be any sorting going on in there, and you obviously want to display the intermediate contents, in the middle of a sort, so, logically, you need to modify whatever does the sorting. Take a step back, gather your thoughts, and come up with a cogent, sensible, question.

Comment: @gelloworld Insert the function print in the while loop after the for loop and for the final output - after the while loop.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow thank you! Would you mind explaining why I have to insert the function print two times (as I am still a tad confused)? Thank you so much once again.

Comment: @gelloworld There are two kinds of outputs (if to exclude the output of the original array): 1 2 4 6 8 (after ith pass) and 
Final array: 1 2 4 6 8

Comment: @VladfromMoscow thank you, but what if I also want to output the original array? How would I do so? Would I have to put a print(a) before the while loop in the bubble _sort? Thanks!

Comment: @gelloworld Output it before the while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add print(a) in every successful swap. So inside bubble sort function -> the iteration For loop -> if (ith > i+1th) successful -> swap and print.